# Java : how do I get the precision part in the decimal?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java : how do I get the part after the decimal point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890472/java-how-do-i-get-the-part-after-the-decimal-point)

In my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890472/java-how-do-i-get-the-part-after-the-decimal-point) I didn't give proper explanation. This is my exact scenario.

I have a `double` variable `d = 1.15`.

I want the number after the decimal point, i.e. "15".

What is best way to achieve this in Java?

I have tried like this:

```
Double d = 1.15;
String str = d.toString();
int len = str.substring(str.indexOf(".")).length() - 1;
int i= (int) (d * (long)Math.pow(10,len) % (long)Math.pow(10,len));
```

But I didn't get the proper answer because when I convert `d.toString()` the answer is `14.999999999999986`.

Comment: Instead of asking new question why not update the old one? There is a functionality to update your question on this site.

Comment: Please don't post the same question twice.  There is plenty of activity on your other question, including a correct answer (which you should accept).

Comment: You should edit your previous post if it's not clear.  See Arjun's answer there, he got it right.

Comment: By the way, you **still** haven't explained what you really mean.  An example is not an explanation.  And "the number after the decimal" is nonsensical from a mathematical stand point.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `d.toString()`, try this:

```
String str = String.format("%.2f", d);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Double x = 1.2345;
Double p = x - Math.floor(x);
String[] sp = p.toString().split("\\.");
```

The `sp[1]` variable will now contain the string `2345`, as long as there is in fact a decimal part to it. If there isn't, `sp` will only have one item in it, so you can check the length and do whatever you want to handle such a situation.