# Javascript toFixed equivalent in java

Tags: java, javascript

I am using `toFixed(2)` in client side (javascript) but in the server side (java) I have to recalculate. how can i do this?

Comment: 'String data = "10223455.3415"; BigDecimal decimal = new BigDecimal(data); System.out.println(decimal.setScale(2,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).toPlainString())‌​;' is working for me

Comment: Maybe that line of code helps you `System.out.println(String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%.2f", 1.23456));`

Comment: JS: `console.log(3.345.toFixed(2)); // 3.35`. Java (15+): `"%.2f".formatted(3.345); // 3.35`.

Answer (score 12):

[`setScale()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale%28int,%20int%29) of [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) will do it for you on server side

```java
import java.math.BigDecimal;
          
public class Main {
    public static void main (String ar[]) {
        float number = 123.123456F;
        BigDecimal numberBigDecimal = new BigDecimal(number);
        System.out.println(numberBigDecimal);
        numberBigDecimal = numberBigDecimal.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
        System.out.println(numberBigDecimal);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1000000023.1253456F if i given this its giving the problem

Comment: i added a comment for the question thats working fine. thanks @Joshi

Comment: seems out of float's range, It is working good check [this](http://ideone.com/tvDC8)

Comment: I do not think this would give an accurate result, for e.g

in javascript Number(1.345).toFixed(2) would give 1.34 whereas in java new BigDecimal(1.345).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP) would give 1.35

Comment: @Sayantan That is so ridiculous. Is there any solution for it?

Comment: @wonsuc unfortunately, I did not find any, so I moved all my precision handling at one layer, since Java's was more close to accurate I moved it to my java layer.

Answer (score 4):

[DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)'s [format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#format%28double%29) method is the equivalent in java to toFixed in javascript.

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.##");
System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(3.1000565));
```

Comment: What do u mean by `float data =1234568.236f;` ?

Comment: DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.##");
 System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(data));
 =  1234568.25
but in js it is giving 1234568.24

Comment: `String data = "10223455.3415";
 BigDecimal decimal = new  BigDecimal(data);
 System.out.println(decimal.setScale(2,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).toPlainString());`

Comment: Big decimal, setScale is the way to go. see Jigar Joshi's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10631844/885902)

Comment: @FernandoTorres please elaborate