# Regex for limiting numbers between 0.01 and 1 - JAVA

Tags: java, regex

I want to find a regex which allows values between 0.01 and 1 , both inclusive upto two decimal places max. 0.00 , 0.0 or 0 is not allowed . Values greater than 1 (eg , 1.01 , 1.1 etc. is not allowed). Can i get help?

Comment: May we ask why you would rather use a regex here rather than a range comparison and `if` statement?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen so because `0.010001` is not acceptable but `0.01` is. Its just a combination of length of decimals & range comparison. I rather do it by simply doing exactly that. length comparison & range comparison

Comment: But `0.010001` is between `0.01` and `1.00`. Could you please clarify?

Comment: I'm not the OP, but i understood so because, the OP mentioned that only 2 decimal places mattered in the regex. So anything beyone 2 decimal places didnt parse through the regex

Comment: What about "1.5e-1"? Is this an allowed input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching for one of good patterns:

- `(^0\.[0-9][1-9]$)`: 0.xy (where x is digit 1-9 and y is digit 0-9)
- `(^0\.[1-9]0*$)`: 0.x (where x is digit 1-9, with optional zero)
- `(^1\.0{1,2}$)|(^1$)`: one of allowed notations for 1 (1, 1.0, 1.00)

`(^0\.[0-9][1-9]$)|(^0\.[1-9]0*$)|(^1\.0{1,2}$)|(^1$)`

With `^` and `$` should handle edge testcases:

```
0
0.0
0.00
0.01 - match
0.1  - match
0.01 - match
0.10 - match 
0.11 - match 
0.1.1
0.11.1
00
00.1.1
1    - match 
1.0  - match
1.00 - match 
1.10
1.11
0.001
0.111
```

See https://regex101.com/r/U4I9sK/2

Answer (score 0):

Not a regex, but a method to return what you expected. You need to do two things: range comparison & length comparison if range is satisified.

Like so,

```
public static boolean isGood(double x){
        return x>=0.01 
            && x<=1.0 
            && String.valueOf(x).split("\\.")[1].length()<=2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say 'allow' do you mean to disallow, ie excluded completely, or are you wanting to convert the long decimal?

If excluding then regex =

```
 ^(1(\.0?0?)?|0?\.(0[1-9]|[1-9]\d?))$
```

This also allows for just '1.'.

if converting, then you can use a combination of if conditions and setScale 'as answered here:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631813/javascript-tofixed-equivalent-in-java'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631813/javascript-tofixed-equivalent-in-java%27)

Comment: Include also `1\.0{1,2}` not to miss 1.0 and 1.00, and it's good.

Comment: you can remove the outer brackets. I would also remove the first `?`, but it's not clear if `"1."` is valid or not (I would argue not - hence remove the `?`).