# How to identify the tenths part of a float in Python?

Tags: python, floating-point, decimal

After looking at the various math, float, and decimal functions in Python, I haven't found what I'm looking for.  In my program, there may be instances when it will return a float and I need the float information so that I can do another function.  Let's say based on the user's input the quotient we're working with is 1.4, which I will represent as X.Y.  How do I isolate Y so that I can use a FOR statement.  (I need the program to do something 4 times in this case.)  I've tried playing with the % function, but that returns the remainder, not the value I'm looking for.  I've tried math.fmod and math.modf.  Again not what I'm looking for.  I looked at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017072/how-to-get-the-decimal-part-of-a-float) too.

Comment: I your case, do you know the amount of digits after the decimal points?

Comment: What input validations is the quotient subject to? If the user enters 8.675309 will the loop run 675309 times?

Comment: @JosefAssad - +1 to your comment for your example value.

Comment: I have the values rounded to the tenth.  So, when a float is returned, I will instruct something to happen 4 times.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like `int((x*10) % 10)` will do it:

```
>>> x = 1.4
>>> int((x*10) % 10)
4
```

Comment: Assuming `x` is always an exact tenth---i.e., a number of the form `n / 10.0` for some integer `n`, it would be somewhat safer to do `int(round(x * 10) % 10)`.  Otherwise you risk getting the wrong answer when `x * 10` is just a smidgen too small as a result of floating-point inaccuracies.  [As it happens, it turns out that with IEEE 754 arithmetic and round-half-to-even, `(n / 10.0) * 10.0 == n` for any exactly representable integer `n`, but that's something of an accident.  It doesn't remain true if you replace `10.0` with `100.0`, for example.]

Comment: "any exactly representable integer n".  Bah.  That should say "Any *sufficiently small* exactly representable integer n."  :-)

Comment: ... which is to say, any `n` not larger than `5 * 2**50`.  Okay, I'll shut up now.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
x = 1.4
y = 10 * (x - int(x))
>>> 4
```

Answer (score 2):

or you could do it as string manipulation

```
x=1.4
whole,fractional = map(int,str(x).split("."))
```

afterwards whole is equal to 1 and fractional is equal to 4... and it should work equally well with negative numbers

Answer (score 0):

Using the following method you can get ***any*** position in a float. That is, tenths, hundredths, thousandths and so on:

```
import math

def get_pos_float(num, unit):
    if unit >= 10:
        num = abs(math.modf(num)[0]) # Get just the fractional part
        num *= 10 # Move the decimal point one place to the right
        return get_pos_float(num, unit/10)
    return int(math.modf(num)[1]) #Return the whole number part

decimalNumber = 13.24
print(get_pos_float(decimalNumber, 10)) # prints the tenths decimal position 2
print(get_pos_float(decimalNumber, 100)) # prints the hundredths decimal position 4
print(get_pos_float(decimalNumber, 1000)) # prints the thousandths decimal position 0
```