# Java: adding floating point numbers with expansions

Tags: java, floating-point, addition

My apologies if that was asked somewhere, but I couldn't find anything that would help me. This is part of my larger program when I want to add numbers and display them, but when I encountered number `0.6` output is not "accurate". I want to display them exactly to one decimal point. How I can achieve this ?

Source Code:

```
public class NumberTest {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        double n = 0.6;
        double sum = 0.0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            System.out.println(sum);
            sum += n;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0.0
0.6
1.2
1.7999999999999998
2.4
3.0
3.6
4.2
4.8
5.3999999999999995
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use println but rather `printf(...)` since printf allows for *formatted* output.

```
System.out.printf("%.1f%n", sum);
```

Or use a DecimalFormat object:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.0");

System.out.println(df.format(sum));
```

And yeah, this is a duplicate question of a duplicate of a duplicate...

Comment: +1 I am sure it was a duplicate for languages around before Java.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Thanks. I'm trying to find the best duplicate because this question really should be closed and there should be a link to a duplicate with an appropriate accepted answer. As you know most of this was borrowed from C (which borrowed it from...?)

Comment: @PeterLawrey: here's a nice related question: [how-to-get-the-decimal-part-of-a-float](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017072/how-to-get-the-decimal-part-of-a-float). 1+ to the answer!