# How do I get the integer portion and the remainder of the number?

Tags: java

How do I get the integer portion and the remainder of the number? For example, I have a number of float type, `123.456789`, and I want to copy the integer portion of the number into an `int` variable and the remainder of the number into a `float` in [java](/questions/tagged/java):

```
float a = 123.456789
int b = 123
float c = 0.456789
```

Comment: There are many ways to do this. Did you try anything on your own?

Comment: Make a string. Split on `.`; then reassign the split strings. Then cast back to your variable's type. Not much to it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017072/how-to-get-the-decimal-part-of-a-float

Comment: How do you want to handle negative numbers (e.g., `float a = -123.456789`)? Should it be -123 and -0.456789? Or perhaps -123 and 0.456789? Or even -124 and 0.543211?

Answer (score 4):

You could do the following:

```
float a = 123.456789f;
int b = (int)a; //Remove the remainder by casting to `int`
float c = a - b;
```

Answer (score 0):

The "overkill" solution:

```
float a = 123.456789f;
int b = (int) Math.floor(a);
float c = a - b;
```

Comment: Why use `floor()` though? Casting to int will always round down.

Comment: @Marv That's why I said this was the "overkill" solution... you've already posted the simple, casting, solution... I just put this to illustrate that there are indeed many ways to do the same thing (some more efficient and clean than others)

Comment: @Marv - casting and `Math.floor` give different results for negative, non-integral numbers. OP didn't specify the desired behavior for negative numbers, however, so it's hard to say which approach is preferred here.

Comment: @TedHopp I would've thought the OP would want `-123.0` and `-0.456789` for `-123.456789` but you're right, we can't say for sure.