# How to add floats but keep/wrap the total within the range 0..1?

Tags: java, android

I'm doing some animation on several alpha values and want to set the values relative to a reference value

```
obj1.alpha = refAlpha + 0.25f;
obj2.alpha = refAlpha + 0.75f;
```

If refAlpha is 0.5 for example then I want obj2.alpha to be 0.25 not 1.25. 
What math function is there to do that?

Comment: why are you asking? is google not working?

Comment: Instead of downvoting why not supply the answer as a quick comment. The reason I'm asking is I've looked at the math class but don't see anything, however surely there must be. I could check myself if the value is > 1.0 and adjust, of course I could, but surely there must be a convenience function I can call instead.

Comment: No google is not working, that is why I'm asking. Give me the search term to find the answer then. And as I've just said I've just read the math documentaiton.

Comment: Now there is an answer, I can reveal I didn't know mod would work on floats. If that's something you don't know its not easy to find out from google.

Comment: here you go lazy one: possible duplicate of [How to get the decimal part of a float?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017072/how-to-get-the-decimal-part-of-a-float)

Comment: Twat. I'm not lazy, just do not know what to search for. Big difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mod operator `%` will do the trick in terms of wrapping. (it works on floats as well as ints).

```
obj1.alpha = (refAlpha + 0.25f) % 1f
obj2.alpha = (refAlpha + 0.75f) % 1f

public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println(1.25f % 1f); // --> 0.25
}
```

Unfortunately, java doesn't quite implement mod to the mathematical definition. `a % b` returns a value in the range `(-b, b)`, as opposed to `[0, b)`. If you are ever subtracting values, the result could therefore be negative. If this is a usecase you are worried about, consider creating a helper function to handle it:

```
public static float mod(float a, float b){
    return ((a % b) + b) % b;
}
```

This will make the result in the range `[0,b)`.